How can I extend mlflow recipes with my custom model
As MLflow recipe says classification and regression solutions are supported by them. However, I want to create anomaly detection solution. Below section shows the MLflow folder structure.
.
├── mlflow
│   ├── recipes
│   │   ├── classification
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── v1
│   │   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │   │       └── recipe.py
│   │   ├── regression
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── v1
│   │   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │   │       └── recipe.py


I am not able to import anomaly detection solution to MLflow recipes without touching the MLflow recipes source code.
I have created same folder structure as mlflow recipe. In my working directory, I have the folder structure as below
├── mlflow
│   └── recipes
│       ├── isolation_forest
│       │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   └── v1
│       │       ├── __init__.py
│       │       └── recipe.py
│       ├── recipe.py
│       └── steps
│           ├── __init__.py
│           └── train.py

I am having a problem in the source code of mlflow recipes. That throws below error
mlflow.exceptions.MlflowException: Failed to find Recipe mlflow.recipes.isolation_forest.v1.RecipeImpl.Please check the correctness of the recipe template setting: isolation_forest/v1

It's not able to find isolation_forest because that folder is not inside in the mlflow recipe source code. However, I want to be able to extend mlflow recipe code and use my custom solution folder
Problem is still existing. Any idea?
